# Firebase functions: cloud storage triggers not working because of insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have a cloud function that is triggered by updates to storage. when I deploy any function that utilises cloud storage, I get an error code 7 and an [insufficient permissions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#cloud-console_4) message in the functions logs.

I have tried following the advice ont he above page and granted Cloud Functions Service Agent to an account I created called <PROJECT_ID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com - I believe this is what the troubleshooting page means by "runtime service account", as that's what I've seen discussed online. I've also given it Storage Legacy Bucket Owner access.

Also the advice I've found online (like [here](https://medium.com/@jppdevelop/how-to-fixed-functions-deploy-error-insufficient-permissions-to-re-configure-a-trig-ger-25a4941e0b6d) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/39#issuecomment-295799385)) seems to be outdated as they did not work for me or invlove account naming formats that don't exist - I'm not even sure if creating a new service account as described above was the right move.

My storage rules are also completely open while I'm developing:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

All other functions work fine, so it's jsut working with storage that's an issue. How do I grant the correct permissions?

EDIT: Various service accounts
[image: Various service accounts]

Comment: From service account creation console in Google Cloud Platform (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) you can view available Storage permissions and create a service account with the correct permissions.

Comment: But what are the correct permissions? And what's the correct account for cloud functions? I'v edited my answer to add an image showing various service accounts on the project.

Comment: @AyseAsude forgot to tag you

Comment: The service account should be the one which you use to initialize Admin SDK on your functions. Permissons depend on what the functions does. Does it need read or write access?

Comment: @AyseAsude I think I've found the right account - it was the one one the firebase console under firebase admin sdk, I assume. I found that account and get it `Cloud Functions Service Agent` permissions - is that right? Ideally I want to read and delete (so write too, I guess). Note: the account already has `Storage Admin` access.

Comment: I think you should give "Cloud functions invoker" permission under the Cloud Functions tab and "Storage Object Admin" under the Cloud Storage tab. Make sure to read the descriptions of permissons before enabling.

Comment: @AyseAsude Did that. In cloud storage I gave the firebase sdk service account both Storage Legacy Bucket Owner access and Storage Object Admin access. In IAM I granted Cloud Functions Service Agent (you can't set functions permissions directly, afaik). Still no luck. I notice the error is saying `give owner permissions to the editor role of the bucket and try again`. Do you know how that can be done?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244118/discussion-between-ayseasude-and-crevulus).

Comment: @AyseAsude I have been phenomenally stupid. I thought the `bucket` included subfolders within the default bucket. i.e. I thought that adding a `/foo` subfolder also created a `foo` bucket. So I was targeting a `foo` bucket that didn't exist. It deploys fine when I remove that.

Comment: @crevulus: Could you elaborate on an answer with your solution to help users that experience a similar problem?

Comment: @AndresFiescoCasasola In my code I was trying to access a bucket via `storage.object().bucket('MY_BUCKET_NAME')`. I thought bucket === directory. It doesn't. As it turns out I was trying to access and entirely different GCP bucket/resource that jsut didn't exist. As soon as I took out the bucket part it worked.

Answer (score 1):

crevulus was trying to access the bucket using:

`storage.object().bucket('MY_BUCKET_NAME')`

There was an error entering the bucket (He used the directory as the bucket name)

By using the directory as a bucket, he was trying to access a GCP bucket/resource that did not exist.

The solution was to remove the bucket part and that solved the problem.